# ASP.NET MVC 5 best approach for outputting and downloading file progress

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, file-io, export-to-csv

I must to create a function which allow an user click a button in browser and request to server to get information from database. The information will be output to a .csv file, after that client able to download it.

I intend to use one of two method of `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`

`protected internal virtual FileStreamResult File(Stream fileStream, string contentType, string fileDownloadName)`

or

`protected internal virtual FileContentResult File(byte[] fileContents, string contentType, string fileDownloadName);`

But the output file size can be up to 4 gigabytes, so I worry the buffering size of a file in `Stream` or `byte[]` will cause server memory leaks.

I split my progress into 2 steps

**Step 1:** output csv file with memory leaks consideration

```
public CsvOutputHelper(List<string> csvHeader)
{
    this._csvHeader = csvHeader;
}

public void OutputFile(List<List<string>> data, string filePath)
{
    // Create the new file and write the header text
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, this._csvHeader.ConvertToCsvRecord());

    // 'StringBuilder' for output file
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine();

    // Line counter
    var lineCounterValue = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        // Create line content of csv file and append it to buffer string
        sb.AppendLine(data[i].ConvertToCsvRecord());

        // Increase value of line counter
        lineCounterValue++;

        // If buffer string is reach to 100 lines or the loop go to the end of data list,
        // output text to file and reset value of buffer string and value of line counter
        if (lineCounterValue == MaxCountOfOutputLine || i == data.Count - 1)
        {
            // Output buffer string
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());

            sb = new StringBuilder();       // Re-create a new instance of 'StringBuilder'
            lineCounterValue = 1;           // Reset line counter value to 1
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** return output `filePath` in server (relative path) to browser and browser request to path to download file.

Is my solution is a good way to implement in that case? Is using `Stream` or `bytes` will to be caused server memory leaks or not? Please explain for me.

Comment: show us a sample text view of your `data` structure

Comment: The question asks one thing, the title another. If you have a lot of data, you shouldn't buffer to an array or a MemoryStream but write to the response stream directly. You shouldn't use StringBuilder like this either as it creates temporary strings. - if you create a StreamWriter on top of the output stream you don't *need* a StringBuilder. With 4GB of data, the last thing you need is another 4GB of temporary strings that need GC

Comment: Sending progress status on the other hand is impossible with just HTTP. You'd need SignalR or WebSockets to send messages to the client

Comment: Now, `FileStreamResult File(Stream fileStream)` is useful when you already have a stream. It *copies* data from that stream to the response's output stream. In your case though you *don't* have a stream with a ready-made CSV. One option would be to write the CSV directly (using the DB's bulk export features) to a temporary file and send it to the client with `File(string path)`. That method will open a stream on top of the temp file and copy the contents to the output stream.

Comment: The problem is that 4GB is a *lot* of data and will take a lot of time just to read it from the source. Even if you use a DbDataReader to read from the DB using a fire hose  cursor and write to the response stream, the operation will still take a lot of time, keep a request open for long and possibly fail for connectivity reasons. It's probably safer to treat this as a long running job, export the data locally and notify the user to download the file once it's finished.

Comment: Check Scott Hanselman's article [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx). It describes the options available for running long background jobs in ASP.NET MVC. Hangfire is a very good option

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your helping :D